# My Music Won't Appear on my OnePlus One

Tags: music

On my OnePlus One, which is currently running Android version 5.1.1 and Cyanogen OS version 12.1, isn't finding music on my device. I got the music onto my phone with my Chromebook, a HP 14, and simply moving the files to my phones "Music" folder. Once disconnected from my laptop, the music won't appear in the "Play Music" app. I know the files are on my phone, since they appear when I look in my file manager.

I've tried hitting the "refresh" button on both the music app and file manager, in addition to clearing the cache on both the applications. I've also rebooted my phone numerous times, and tried using a SD re-scanner with no avail.

This problem has happened on my phone before, and I solved it by clearing all the music data and putting it all back on my device. Still, I would really prefer not to do this, since it is kind of a pain.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I thought that Play Music sees the music you've uploaded to Google Play Music (google.com/music), not the music that is locally saved on your device.

Comment: @RMarkwald It should see both

Comment: @Mark What format is the music in?

Comment: Have you tried whether other music apps can see your files? If they don't, it might be worth clearing cache and data of the media library, to force the media scanner to entirely rebuild it. Also watch out for any `.nomedia` files in the path to those files.

Comment: @LJD200 Its MP3.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps - Media Storage and do force stop and clear data. Reboot and tell us the results. Alternatively, if the Android is rooted, clear the contents of the directory `/data/data/com.android.providers.media/` and reboot.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

An [Android Central thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-htc-rezound/193790-music-not-showing-up-play-music.html) discusses this issue and has several things to try:

1. Force stop Google Play Music and clear its data before reopening it. This may lose some data such as playlists but hopefully not the music itself.
2. Uninstall and reinstall all the updates to Google Play Music.
3. Ensure that the folder that the music is stored in or any parent folders don't have .nomedia files in them. You may need to enable hidden files in your file manager to see these files.

Unfortunately, some of these solutions seem temporary but it may be worth a try.

Comment: I tried all that you suggested. The force stop did nothing, as well as the update suggestion. Clearing the data lost MORE music. Thanks for the suggestions anyway. I think I'm just going to replace all the music, and see if that works.

Comment: @Mark Very sorry about not being able to fix the issue and the data loss. This isn't the first time I've heard about this issue on a OnePlus One but that could be coincidence; I don't know whether the issue is related to the device... Hopefully replacing all the music solves the issue permanently. I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From [OP's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132904/my-music-wont-appear-on-my-oneplus-one/132913#comment168641_132913),

> In the end, I didn't need to replace all my music. I merely connected my phone via USB cord to my laptop and browsed through my music files. I think that it rescanned my files, and the songs reappeared on the device.